# How to sum multi-dimensional arrays in PHP without merging values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, sum

Let's say I have the following array and I want to add up the sub-array values using PHP:

```
$summary = array(
    "person1" => array(
         question1 => '3',
         question2 => '5'),
    "person2" => array(
         question1 => '2',
         question2 => '3'),
    "person3" => array(
         question1 => '1',
         question2 => '2')
);
```

How can I output the individual array sums for each person, rather than totaling all values from all sub-arrays?  For instance:

```
$summary = array(
    "person1" => array(
         questions => '8'),
    "person2" => array(
         questions => '5'),
    "person3" => array(
         questions => '3')
);
```

I seem to be able to add it up to 16 using a foreach loop, but what I need is individual values so I can get the highest value and lowest value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$summaryTotals = Array();
foreach ($summary as $_summary => $_questions)
  $summaryTotals[$_summary] = Array('questions'=>array_sum($_questions));
var_dump($summaryTotals);
```

Loop through all people, get the sum of the questions, and place them in the same key as they came from.

---

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["person1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["questions"]=>
    int(8)
  }
  ["person2"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["questions"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["person3"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["questions"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an awesome answer, but wouldn't I have to do two foreach loops?  First loop through the summary array, then each subarray?

Comment: @TymArtist: It is, I'm just taking advantage of a built-in function of PHP, [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

Comment: I used your solution and was able to get the result I wanted by adding a second foreach loop.  Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what's different about the array you're running against and what you have posted? I was basing my solution off how you indented your array, and took liberties when it came to your (what I thought to be) missing syntax.

Comment: You know what, it was a tri-level array not a dual-level array, which probably accounts for the differential.  I'll know next time to post the third level, it just seemed excessive :).

Answer (score 3):

So you have an array of arrays and want to return an array of the sums of each subarray?

```
function sumArrays($array){
    return array_map("array_sum",$array);
}
```

All you'd need to do then, is call `max` on the returned array

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it.

```
$summary = array();

foreach($data as $name => $questions)
{
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($questions as $question => $answer)
    {
        $sum += $answer;
    }
    summary[$name]['questions'] = $sum;
}
```

Initialize the sum value, sum up each set of questions, stash the sum value, and repeat until finished.  You could put array_sum() into the mix instead of the inner foreach loop.  I always forget about PHP's array functions.  That would be this:

```
$summary = array();

foreach($data as $name => $questions)
{
    summary[$name]['questions'] = array_sum($questions);
}
```

Much shorter and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the existing array, find the sum of marks for all questions for a given person and replace the existing value ( an array ) with the newly created array:

```
foreach($summary as $person => $person_arr) {
        $summary[$person] = array('question' => array_sum($person_arr));
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/TSQNl)

Answer (score 0):

Simple function like:

```
function sumtwoDimensionalArrWithKey($twoDimensionalArr,$key_value){

    foreach($twoDimensionalArr as $twoDimensionalArrValue){
        foreach($twoDimensionalArrValue as $key=> $value){
            if ($key == $key_value) {
                $total += $value;
            }
        }    
    }

    return $total;
}
```

It can be called like:

```
echo sumtwoDimensionalArrWithKey($twoDimensionalArr,'field_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

For functional-style syntax that delivers the exact desired output, call `array_map()` and return a new associative subarray contain the sum for each row encountered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hJlPk))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($questions) => ['questions' => array_sum($questions)], $summary)
);
```